# iOS 14 Widget Deep Link to React-Native app failing

Tags: ios, react-native, swiftui, widgetkit

I have an iOS14 widget that I want to deep link to a screen in my (React-Native) app.

I've set up the deep link on the app side and I can open the desired screen from safari when testing.

example link: `myapp://detail/123`

AppDelegate.m is set up like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  
  if([url.scheme hasPrefix:@"myapp"]) {
    return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
  }
  ...
}
```

...then I have a working receiver in the RN code that uses `Linking` to process the URL. All good.

The issue is that when I trigger the link on my widget it opens the app but doesn't go via AppDelegate and so the link isn't processed.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        ...
    }
    .widgetURL(URL(string: "myapp://detail/\(myIdValue)"))
}
```

I've added the value `myapp` to the `URLScheme` value in my main app's info.plist and then the `URL Types` > `URL Identifier` value in my widget's info.plist.

I'm probably missing something obvious here but does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Which size widget is this? small?

Comment: I have 3 sizes - small, med and large

Comment: Use this for med and large : ````var body: some View {
                        Link(destination: "myapp://detail/\(myIdValue)") {
                            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                    }```

Comment: ok, i'll give it a go. Can I ask why this should work?

Comment: check this : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651786

Comment: Also, one more thing do the same open URL method code inside the didFinish just needs to change a little bit.

Comment: @RajaKishan on `Link` works great for Medium and Large but is there a way to plug this in for Small?

Comment: My suggestion is to don’t give to main zstack. Use sub view

Comment: perfect thanks - widgetURL works with small when not on the ZStack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t gives direct widget URL to parent view. Use subview. Like this.

```
var body: some View {

 ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
        
    }
    .widgetURL(URL(string: "myapp://detail/\(myIdValue)"))
}
}
```

Also, use Link for medium and large size widget.

```
var body: some View { 
    Link(destination: "myapp://detail/(myIdValue)") { 
       ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) { ... } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me about widget Url in android native for react native deep linking

Answer (score 0):

Does your app support multiple scenes? If so, you need to implement `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` in your scene delegate instead of your app delegate.